# twitter bootstrap width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have very strange behavior of table cell width on my page. I am working on my custom widget and have table with 4 columns. First and last column have width 30px. If i have reduced page size its width is equal 0px. Why?

```
.TimelineWidget .move {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}

.TimelineWidget .rule {
    width: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}


<table class="TimelineWidget">
    <tr class="inner">
        <td class="move left"></td>
        <td class="rule">
            bla bla
        </td>
        <td class="streams">
        bla bla
        </td>
        <td class="move right"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have used twitter bootstrap. Is this framework broken my style?

---

**I found solution but i can`t close this post before 7 hour**. 
Width of all my columns is more width of table. I used table-layout:fixed; for correct calculate it.

Comment: Post your results in the form of an answer and approve.

Comment: Its about 2 and a half years. That is way more than the 7 hours you needed to wait to post the answer.